# Regex expression to separate time and replace it with separators

Tags: regex

I need a regex to separate a time string written this way: `2019 08 24 - 154315631.jpg`.

The last 9 digits (before the extension) are the time. First I need to remove the last 3 digits and then I need to separate like this: `2019 08 24 - 15:43:15.jpg`

Comment: `(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})\d{3})\.jpg` will do it, with the three capture groups containing the hour, minute and second, respectively. If the extension is not necessarily `'jpg'` you might be able to change `\.jpg` to `\.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can grab everything you need into 4 groups and skip the last 3 digits before an extension

$1 - `(.*?-\s\d\d)` - `2019 08 24 - 15`

$2 - `(\d\d)` - `43`

$3 - `(\d\d)` - `15`

$4 - `(.*)` - `.jpg`

and replace the matched string with the contents of the groups, separating the groups **$1**, **$2** and **$3** with a colon

```js
"2019 08 24 - 154315631.jpg".replace(/(.*?-\s\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d)\d*(.*)/, "$1:$2:$3$4");
```